# Synchronize AWS EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have been looking for a way to synchronize files between my EC2 web servers .
However in most of the places it is mentioned that S3 can be used in such cases . However my question is S3 provides for only static web hosting , whereas i have php files on my web servers . So how do i synchronize them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably to periodically run rsync to sync the changes on one host to another. There are also bidirectional tools similar to rsync, such as [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). You could use lsyncd to monitor the filesystem, which starts Unison to then perform a sync. [Here's](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2011/04/details-of-two-way-sync-between-two-ubuntu-machines/) a tutorial.

Another popular and simple way is to have a file server where you store your PHP files. These directories are shared via [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) and mounted by the actual webservers. This file server doesn't have to be powerful. With caching the file system performance is usually pretty good. Synchronisation is of course not instant, though quite good. It's usually good enough for a webserver and easy to set up.

Other more complex options are distributed file systems and related systems, such as [GFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_file_system), [GlusterFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlusterFS), [DRBD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Replicated_Block_Device). I'll leave it to yourself to investigate these, but they're considered quite complex. They sync almost real-time but can be hard to set up and troubleshoot.

Comment: thanx for the answer !! i guess unison is perfect for my needs !!

Answer (score 1):

Martijn provided a good answer to your question, but I believe the question is wrong. Once you have more then one web server you should reconsider your deployment strategy and move to scripted/automated/agile/continious (or whatever is the buzzword these days) deployment.

There are many possible scenarios, this answer is a good place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005298/best-practices-for-code-web-application-deployment

Comment: That's definitely true. Proper deployment provides many advantages to simply syncing source-code between servers. Deployed applications still often need some kind of centralized storage for user-data, session-data, etc. This can be a central database, cloud-storage such as S3 or something else. I see many people struggle when they scale up from a simple stack with local files. Rewriting your storage layer isn't always easy or possible so a way to horizontally scale storage is worth looking into, as well a learning about deployment tools.