# How to setup a backup SSL apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

In case of my MAIN server crashing, I'd like to be able to  change the DNS IP address to another (BACKUP) server, in order to reduce the system's downtime.

MAIN server = https:// MAIN_WEBSITE /

BACKUP server = https:// BACKUP_WEBSITE /

**How would I be able to have to accomplish this?**

ex:

https:// MAIN_WEBSITE / on MAIN server crashes so I change the DNS IP address to the BACKUP server:

https:// MAIN_WEBSITE / on BACKUP server now "acts" as the MAIN server (in SSL) until we can resolve the MAIN server issues.

The server's in question are in AWS.

Thanks!

PS: is it also possible for the BACKUP server to have

HTTPS:// MAIN_WEBSITE /

and

HTTPS:// BACKUP_WEBSITE / ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in your PS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Floating IP Cloud Design Pattern](http://en.clouddesignpattern.org/index.php/CDP:Floating_IP_Pattern), this can be implemented in AWS following this article:

[Leveraging Multiple IP Addresses for Virtual IP Address Fail-over in 6 Simple Steps](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/2127188135977316)

Another thing is you must keep sync files in both servers, for this can be used rsync or other solutions. Take a look in this link:

[Synchronize AWS EC2 instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/569002/synchronize-aws-ec2-instances)

Comment: elastic IP address is exactly what I needed. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a reliable approach because ISPs caching policies may lead to the old record being retained even with a low TTL.

Instead you should setup a loadbalancer of some kind behind a unique public IP address (that you set in your DNS record). For instance with [Keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/), you would list your servers, associate ways to check that they are running and add the behaviour you want in order to handle the main server going down (a `sorry_server`, a `quorum_down` script call or simply both servers in the usable pool).